# Can you add docker repository to apt-cacher-ng?

Tags: apt, package-management, docker, repository, proxy

My debian 11 server1 doesn't have internet access and it installs cached debian packages from another server2 that has `apt-cacher-ng` installed. The `sources.list` file in server1  points to `apt-cacher-ng` via `nginx` reverse proxy in server2.

According to docker.com, I have to add
`echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`

How would `apt-cacher-ng` work with this? Is it possible to pull and build docker images/containers via `apt-cacher-ng`?

Currently, in server2 `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf` the line `Remap-dockercom: http://docker.cache ; file:backends_docker_com`. And the `backend_docker_com` file has the following contents: `https://download.docker.com/linux/debian` The domain name of Server2 where caching is going on is `ace`

On Server1, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00-proxy`, the following contents are there:

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://ace:3142"; }
Acquire::https { Proxy "https://ace:3142"; }
Acquire::http::Proxy::ace DIRECT
```

I am still unable to build images from server1

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cacher-ng` is specifically designed to act as a proxy for APT package repositories; it can’t be used for container images.

Docker can use a general-purpose proxy. To set that up, see [the Docker daemon documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy); briefly, create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` containing

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxy:port"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://yourproxy:port"
```

with the appropriate values, then reload the configuration (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart docker`).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the first problem was setting up the Docker package repository (the `echo` command). I misread the rest of the question.

Comment: I thought that docker repository was not setup correctly. I  am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Using the systemd method, I did `docker pull debian` and got this error: `Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.1.8 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`